Access a TTY on Linux from a Windows app that only understands COM ports
I have this working situation:
Windows putty<--->ssh<---->Linux<--->/dev/ttyUSB0<--->hardware

Running tio /dev/ttyUSB0 when logged into the Linux box via putty works as I would hope, but I also have a Windows app that can talk to COMx:, where it expects to find the hardware that is actually attached to the Linux box through /dev/ttyUSB0. How can I transparently redirect COMx: to the Linux box?
I've seen this question, but it seems to be a solution for having the hardware on the Windows machine.
